# How can I automatically generate an index from headings in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

Let's say I have this:

`* Title
** Subtitle 1
   some text
** Subtitle 2
*** Sub-Subtitle 1
    some text
*** Sub-Subtitle 2`

How can I automatically generate an index with links to all those headings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3rd party org-contrib package `org-toc` implements this.

Binging it shows several implementations. Here are two:

[1] http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/

[2] https://github.com/snosov1/org-toc